# .plist Data can not be Loaded From NSArray to NSDictionary

Tags: uitableview, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

I am fairly new to Objective-C.

I have created on .plist in which all data stored in `Response` Dictionary.

```
NSString *myListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"OffersList" ofType:@"plist"];
dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:myListPath];
tableData = [dic objectForKey:@"Response"];
```

Now i have converted that `tabledata` to Dictionary.

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.titleLabel.text = [dict  objectForKey:@"title"];
 cell.nowLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"price"];
 cell.saveLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"rondel"];
```

Now, Problem is that it only load's first 10 data.
I am also tried to print in log but after 10th data it's values seen as `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a dump of the whole `dic` so that you can check exactly what data it contains:

```
NSLog(@"Content of tableData", [dic description]);
```

Then double check the log content for the `tableData` element with the .plist content.

Comment: I have tried this but as i told you,it only load's 10 data after that whole **tableview** is with empty cell.

Comment: are your sure your plist is correct? could you check and ensure that the 11th element is correct, specifically? could you try and remove it?

Comment: Yup,i checked it before asking question here.I also tried delete item no 11. but `NO Result`

Comment: i am near about to solution.What i am doing is i tried with change the small tableview size.And i got only first three data.after that all value null in log.Any `IDEA` how ?